# Configuring domain in web API using Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Switching from MVC to web API way, and using CookieHeaderValue to configure cookie. The only parameter which is not getting set in browser is domain. Please suggest, what could be missing here:

```
var Coki = new CookieHeaderValue("session-Id", "123");
Coki.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(2);
Coki.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
Coki.Path = "/";
Coki.Secure = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

In IIS settings, there is a configuration- Application Request Routing. This helps IIS to function as a load balancer. Due to a setting in this configuration, all the domain were overwritten with the application domain. 
It was overwriting the domain with the application fullname in every request. Hence, we disable this property of ARR and get it working. Property name - "Reverse rewrite host in response headers."